# How to react to "generic" answers to unclear questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, close-reasons, low-quality-posts

#### Scenario

Just now I saw an answer to a question which is unclear (at least, to me).

- First of all, the question lacks an MCVE. The body says, "I am facing a problem where in my application `free()` function call doesnt return back sometimes" but there's no code.
- Secondly, the basic idea behind question is "Can there be any situation.... where X can happen?" which seems to be too broad and off-topic.

I voted appropriately, but I noticed a very generic answer ("It can happen in P,Q,R cases.....") to the question, which I don't agree to be qualified as an *answer*.

I have already commented on the answer, but the OP for the answer (disclaimer: OP is highly knowledgeable in the added tag and has much longer association with SO than me) seems to have a different opinion about the question **and** the answer.

> .....I think a generic question about why XYZ might fail is much more useful to SO than some localized scenario which is only useful to the OP...

but I thought there's a dedicated close reason as no-MCVE, specifically when OP mentions "XYZ happens in my code".

The points mentioned in the *generic* answer should be the basic debugging effort from the OP, IMHO.

#### Question

Is my judgement correct? What does the community say about it? Should this kind of questions be answered? Moreover, am I misjudging the requirement for *MCVE*?

*P.S - I have not linked the Q&A to avoid meta effect, but if that helps to explain the scenario in more detail, I can do that*.

Comment: This fall into the "unclear what you're asking" question without any code. And when there is some (or too much) code falls into the "we're not here to debug your code please provide a MVCE".

Comment: Lundin's answer is correct and sufficient to answer that question and no doubt helps the OP focus on the real problem.  Sure,it is a crap question but the odds that you will *ever* get a [c] programmer to post repro code that demonstrates how he corrupted the heap are forever zero.  Surely this question has been answered before, you could dig up the dup and CV with that dup.  Meh.  Heap corruption bugs are the [regex] of the C tag.

Comment: @HansPassant as I mentioned in the comment below the answer, the answer has nothing wrong in it. I'm just trying to understand and better _my_ judgement on MCVE requirement. This Q&A serves as an example to me. If i'm wrong, I'll get a chance to correct myself, no? :)

Comment: I do feel that more "generalized" or at least more agnostic answers are of greater benefit to the broader SO userbase. Many times I have come across a question/answer that nearly perfectly helps, BUT it isn't broad enough to cover my specific case. Where as a slightly broader answer would have...

Comment: @robertdavid maybe I'm using the wrong words here, but it's not an issue with "generalized" answer. The problem here is, a "generic" approach for the answer to a broad question, can never be a good or complete answer. I point out , say, 10 possible scenario as the reason, and OP may have the 11th (_or 111th._) scenario in the code causing the issue. How does that help? We're not here to create a _textbook_ or _blog_ after all, are we? :)

Comment: Ok thanks @SouravGhosh , I understand it better now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just vote to close the question, maybe downvote the answer, and move on. We can't stop people from answering bad questions (except by closing the question early enough). The answer you mention might be useful as a ['canonical'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/canonical/info) answer, but if that is really the case, it definitely needs a good *question*.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your view, and to mention, (no offense) the answer is not anywhere _near_ `'canonical'` answer. I quote `"There might be duplicates of why XYZ might fail, but it is less work writing this answer than finding a duplicate"`. Sigh. :(

Comment: Also, I don't want to downvote the answer, there's nothing wrong with the content, I'm interested in whether it's OK to provide these kind of `Maybe..Could be..Perhaps` types of answer.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Well, if you think the answer is useful, why do you complain about it at all? Remember that correctness is only a small contributor to usefulness.

Comment: Well, there are quite some meta-posts about making closure faster, or make it count more. Even relatively new ones. But there's a very vocal crowd who thinks "no question is ever bad".

Comment: @Deduplicator IMHO, there's also a difference between `nothing wrong` (as I mentioned) and `useful` (as you mentioned). There are a plenty of things which can be attributed as `nothing wrong` but certainly, they are not bound to he `useful`. Straightway example: Correct answers to dupe questions.

Comment: @SouravGhosh You vote on posted based on whether or not you think they're useful, not whether or not they're correct.  If a post is correct, but not useful, you should be downvoting it.  Conversely, if a post is useful, despite a few minor inaccuracies, it may well merit upvotes.

Answer (score 15):

I think I'm the one who wrote that answer, so here is my take on it.

---

Regarding the moderation part:

There are some things to consider. First of all, MCVE only applies to questions asking about a specific coding problem. Then there is the close reasons "questions asking for debugging help/why is this code not working", which *only* applies to questions asking for help with finding errors in their code (regardless of if they posted the code or not).

MCVE and that close option may or may not apply to this specific case. It is not necessarily black or white. There is no requirement that every question on SO must always be accompanied with code.

---

Regarding the contents:

The thing that was special here was: while the OP indeed had some very specific, localized problem, he seemed to be making an effort of keeping his question generic, so that it would be of interest to more people than himself. He indicated that this was his intention in comments. If so, then that's an entirely good thing. And unselfish - he is sweating with some specific, localized problem, and yet puts the quality of SO for future readers before his own needs! Now, how common is *that*, among new users?

Part of the reason why I wrote an answer is because I want to encourage quality-concerned new users, who actually truly grasp the SO purpose, to stay on the site. Rather than to shoot them down and scare them off.

What happened to this user is that he got completely bandwagon'd in comments and down/close votes. It may or may not have been justified. If someone starts questioning the quality of his post, the bandwagon usually follows.

If he had posted all code that caused his problem, we could solve his specific bug and make him happy. But it would be yet another localized post with little value to future readers.

I'm not sure if that was actually the case, but I saw some hints of a potentially great question, namely "What causes are there that would cause `free()` to crash?". I don't remember seeing such a question among our "canonical duplicates" even though this is quite a commonly-encountered problem. We could do with one! Therefore I wrote a generic answer, listing all the possible causes.

Now the question was closed and I can't seem to find it. I'm not sure if it was "canonical duplicate" material or just a bad question.

As a side note, who volunteers to write a [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) community wiki post about the causes why `free()` might fail?

Comment: Sir, thank you in first place for stepping up and posting an answer, though I was not trying to involve the _particular_ Q&A into the discussion, but it seems we cannot avoid the effect after all. Secondly, as I already mentioned, I was rather trying to seek opinions about the answering policy, rather that judging the merit of the answer itself. Thirdly, if you think a cannonical Q&A is required for this category, I can volunteer for that, if you want, but I believe there are already valid dupes, so another answer will be either flagged as duplicate/closed. How to proceed?

Comment: [The question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37918455/free-call-in-c-not-returning) is now deleted. I cast the final vote more out of mercy for the person who asked the question than anything. It was getting far too much attention from this Meta post. If you want to post a canonical question about cases where `free()` might fail, I think you should ask a new question, even if you repost your answer almost verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

Ask them more information about the question and tell them where he fails, I think it's better for the users to **instruct** them than just close their question or downvote them.

Comment: Well, that has already been done, and my comments also got upticks there (seems some people agree to my views). Thanks. But somehow this question also concerns the behavior from the answerers, can you share your view on that front, too?

Comment: I mean that we should instruct them in using this website